# Warnings about peer in fresh install of AngularClass angular2-webpack-starter

Tags: npm, webpack

I am new to angular2.
I just installed https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter and I am a bit puzzled with a lot of warnings.

First, I have no idea if those warnings are harmless or not... Or if I may encounter an issue later. Do I have to worry about them ?

I do not understand some as it should be OK. See (1)

So, do I have to try to correct them ? There is a risk to break other packages, right ? See (2) & (3).

Secondly, some warnings are incompatible between them. How do you manage that ?

See (4) tslint@^3.9.0 /(3) tslint@4.0.0-dev.* 
and (4) rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 / (2) rxjs@5.0.0-rc.2

Thanks for your advices.
Regards.

Here are the warnings:

(1)

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.1.1
+-- @angular/compiler@2.1.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.1.1
+-- @angular/forms@2.1.2
```

Whereas in package.json I have:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
```

(2)

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-rc.2
| `-- symbol-observable@1.0.4
```

in package.json

```
   "rxjs": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
```

(3)

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY tslint@4.0.0-dev.1
| +-- colors@1.1.2
| +-- diff@3.0.1
```

package.json :

```
 "devDependencies": {
...
      "tslint": "^4.0.0-dev.0",
```

(4)

```
npm WARN @angular/http@2.1.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.1.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/forms@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/forms@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.1.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of tslint@^3.9.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN tslint-loader@2.1.5 requires a peer of tslint@^3.0.0 but none was installed.
```

Comment: Check your npm version, you may need to upgrade it. npm i npm -g

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.
codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.4 requires a peer of tslint@^3.9.0 but none was installed.
And
tslint-loader@2.1.5 requires a peer of tslint@^3.0.0 but none was installed.